# Prevent user from leaving DataGridViewRow in WinForms parent/child form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form with a read-only datagridview on the left and various controls on the right.

Instead of allowing users to edit the datagridview row directly, I load the values for the selected record into the controls on the right, where they can do the editing.

However, after changing values on the right, I select a new row in the grid, the RowValidating event is not getting fired, or is not getting fired before the RowEnter event.

In this scenario, how can I prevent the user from moving to a different row on the grid if the validation of the child controls for the current row fails?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If I understand things correctly you don't want the user to be able to change rows in the grid to the left until they have finished their editing in the controls to the right? 

If so, what is stopping you from just using a simple `bool` flag as a `class` attribute.  Setting that flag to `false` when editing starts and `true` when editing is done. When the user tries to change the current cell in the grid to the left you can check the status of the boolean flag and handle it arbitrarily in, for example, the grid's `CurrentCellChanged` event.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was.  I had a Validating event handler on one of the textbox fields on the right side that was interfering with the whole process.  Once I took that out, everything is behaving as expected.